# Reading lines from sys.stdin however ends up in a loop

Tags: python, svg, stdin, sys

I am trying to read lines from a text file however I get stuck trying to access the lines, or so I think.

```
import sys
import math
import re

CANVAS_HEIGHT = 500
CANVAS_WIDTH = 500

SVG_HEADER = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="%d" height="%d">\n'
SVG_BOUNDING_BOX = '<rect x="0" y="0" width="%d" height="%d" style="stroke:#000;fill:none" />\n'
SVG_LINE = '<line x1="%d" y1="%d" x2="%d" y2="%d" style="stroke:#000" />\n'
SVG_FOOTER = '</svg>'

print SVG_HEADER % (CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT)
print SVG_BOUNDING_BOX % (CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT)

try:
    line_number = 0
    for S in sys.stdin:
        line_number = line_number + 1

        L = S.split()
        try:
            x0 = float(L[1])
            y0 = float(L[2])
            x1 = float(L[3])
            x1 = float(L[4])
        except:
            sys.stderr.write('Error in line %d: %s\n' % (line_number, S))

    print SVG_LINE, x0, y0, x1, y1
except:
    sys.stderr.write('Cannot open: %s\n' % sys.argv[1])

print '%s\n' % (SVG_FOOTER)
```

In the terminal, I get stuck at the

for S in sys.stdin:

If you were wondering, the purpose of this code is to take lines and place them into svg format. All the sys.stderr.write is just specs from my prof.

The lines i am reading are just like

"line 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0"

a bunch of times.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add a tag for the programming language you are using and to remove the current tags, all of which appear to be very general but not helpful to others finding your question.

Comment: How do you invoke your program?

Comment: python lines_to_svg.py lines_files.txt

Comment: That syntax does not connect `lines_files.txt` to your program's standard input, so your `for` loop reads from the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this line:

```
for S in sys.stdin:
```

your program isn't stuck, it is waiting for input. Try typing:

```
line 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0
```

followed by the EOF indicator (in UNIX and derivatives: `^D`. In MS-DOS and derivatives: `^Z`). You may need to enter the EOF indicator twice.

If you are trying to read from a text file instead of the console, you'll want to either open the text file in your program, or use file redirection in your shell:

Option 1:

```
# If you always use the same input file:
with open("somefile.txt") as fp:
    for S in fp:
        ...
```

or

```
# If you always have exactly one command-line parameter:
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fp:
    for S in fp:
```

or, my favorite, because [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) allows you to specify one, several, or no command-line parameters,

```
# If you want to specify file(s) on the command line
import fileinput
...
for S in fileinput.input():
    ...
```

Option 2:

```
$ python my_program.py < somefile.txt
```

or

```
C:\Users\me> python my_program.py < somefile.txt
```

Comment: Should of added the command line: python lines_to_svg.py lines_file.txt

Comment: Try `python lines_to_svg.py < lines_file.txt` instead.

Comment: I can't modify command line input as my prof will be using "python lines_to_svg.py lines_file.txt" to test my program

Comment: Then consider one of the `option 1` choices in my answer.

Comment: Ya, I used fileinput and it worked. That being said, I have used sys.stdin in the past in a very similar fashion and it worked.